# .NET Generic Parameters with Generic Interface Arguments

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to create a structure where a base class has a generic property that must meet an interface requirement, and the class which accepts that generic argument will be used as a generic parameter on another class.

Similar to the following example:

```
Public MustInherit Class MainClass(Of T As {iThing(Of IParameter)})
    Public Property s As T
End Class

Public Interface IParameter
End Interface

Public Interface ithing(Of Tx)
    Property x As Tx
End Interface

Public Class Thing(Of Tx) : Implements iThing(Of Tx)
    Property x As Tx Implements iThing(Of Tx).x
End Class

Public Class MyMainClass1(Of T As Thing(Of IParameter)) : Inherits MainClass(Of T)
End Class

Public Class SubMainClass1 : Inherits MyMainClass1(Of Thing(Of MyParameter))
    Public Class myParameter : Implements iParameter
    End Class
End Class
```

There will be many classes like the `SubMainClass` which will define their own parameters, all implementing the `IParameter` interface.  However, the `Thing(Of MyParameter)` does now not match the constraint on the `MainClass` giving the following compile error

> error BC32044: Type argument 'Thing(Of MySubMainClass1.myParameter)' does not inherit from or implement the constraint type 'Thing(Of IParameter)'.
>           public class MySubMainClass1 : inherits MyMainClass1(of Thing(of MyParameter) )

Is there a way to make a generic constraint accept an object which has its own Generic parameter based on an interface?

**Update**

This will work, but I really want to avoid this if possible as it means adding extra complication to all of the sub classes.  I am hoping this is not the only option.

Split out the high level generic parameters into two:

```
Public Mustinherit Class MainClass2(Of T as {iThing(of Tp)}, Tp As IParameter)
    Public Property s As T
End Class
```

Make the relevant subclasses pass two generic parameters

```
Public Class MyMainClass2(Of T As Thing(of Tp), Tp As IParameter)
   Inherits MainClass2(of T, Tp)
End Class

Public Class MySubMainClass2
    Inherits MyMainClass2(Of Thing(Of MyParameter), MyParameter )

    Public Class myParameter
        Implements iParameter
    End Class
End Class
```